# In R, how to split a data into list of multiple subsets based on multiple categorical variables?

Tags: r, split, subset

In my data frame, I have a lot of logical variables and I want to split the data frame into multiple subsets conditional on each logical variable is TRUE. For example, let's suppose this is my df:

```
     V1    V2    V3 V4
1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  2
2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  5
3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  4
```

So I want to have three subsets:

```
[1]
     V1    V2    V3 V4
1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  2
2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  5

[2]
     V1    V2    V3 V4
1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  2
2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  4

[3]
     V1    V2    V3 V4
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  5
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "suppose this is my df" -- not possible since `data.frame(V = c(T, T, F))` does not print like T T F. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 for some guidance on writing code that makes an easily-reproduced example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple lapply loop should do the trick:

```
read.table(textConnection("V1 V2 V3 V4
T  T  F  2
T  F  T  5
F  T  F  4"), header=T) -> df

lapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), function(i) {
    subset(df, df[[i]])
})

[[1]]
    V1    V2    V3 V4
1 TRUE  TRUE FALSE  2
2 TRUE FALSE  TRUE  5

[[2]]
     V1   V2    V3 V4
1  TRUE TRUE FALSE  2
3 FALSE TRUE FALSE  4

[[3]]
    V1    V2   V3 V4
2 TRUE FALSE TRUE  5
```

Comment: or simply  `lapply(df[,-4], subset, x=df)`

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is very simple. For the first subset you can use:

```
subset1 <- df[df[ ,1]==T, ]
```

in which the function takes out the rows that has the first column V1's value of `T`.

Of course if you wanna set up a whole function for that job for later use, then @thc's solution is best. But in case you just need to get 3 subsets nicely and quickly, try the above.

I'll let you figure out how to do the rest with `subset2` and `subset3`.